# how to Parse Json without object in VB.NET with “Newtonsoft”

Tags: vb.net, json.net

```
Dim json As String = rawresp
Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)

For Each item As JObject In jsonArray
    textboxLast.Text = item.SelectToken("id").ToString
Next
```

and the JSON is:

```
{"id": "546546","name": "Msallem Hamadi","address": "street airport"}
```

i want to extract 546546 to textboxLast.Text but there is no output and no error .

Comment: why are you trying to declare it as a JArray when it's not an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON does not represent an array, so you do not need a loop here.

If you are trying to extract the `id` value you can simply do this:

```
textboxLast.Text = CStr(jsonObject("id"))
```